# How to export a Project Builder for CE 6.0 subproject as a project?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-ce, platform-builder

I have an OS design project with some subprojects, I would like to try to compile one of this subprojects using the SDK of other platform. I don't have the BSP used to create this SDK, so I cannot simply add the subproject to a new OS Design for this platform. I think that the only way is to convert the subproject to a new project and compile it using the new SDK, is it possible? or should I have to manually copy the sources into a new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually copy the source files into anew project as far as I know.